# Set vuejs2 firebase config dynamically

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

Currently am setting firebase credentials in vuejs2 via

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import VueFire from 'vuefire';

var config = {
   apiKey: "",
   authDomain: "",
   databaseURL: "",
   projectId: "",
   storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
};

Vue.use(VueFire);
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const firebasestore = firebase;
Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebasestore;

export { firebasestore }
```

What i want is to set the  credentials dynamically example on created component not fixed values of apkey, authdomain, databaseUrl, projectid storage bucked

So something like. In my component i would like to set the credentials like

```
created(){
 this.$firebase.set ...// here set the config details
}
```

Can this be set this way rather than set the config on fixed values.

Comment: I don't think that's possible since the Firebase app needs the config to be initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Vuex Store where you have a mutation that initializes Firebase.

Then you can call an action to fetch Firestore.

Here is an example (very unpolished POC...):

## Store

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {},
    actions: {
        fetchFirebase({ commit, state }) {

            firebase.firestore().collection("myCollection")
                .doc("myDocument")
                .get()
                .then(doc => {
                    console.log(doc.data());
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });

        },
    },
    mutations: {
        initialiseFirebase(state, val) {
            firebase.initializeApp(val);
        },
    }
});
```

## Component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="initFirebase" class="button">Init Firebase</button>
    <button @click="fetchFirestore" class="button">Fetch Firestore</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },

  methods: {
    initFirebase() {
      const config = {
        apiKey: ".....",
        authDomain: ".....",
        databaseURL: ".....",
        projectId: "....."
      };
      this.$store.commit("initialiseFirebase", config);
    },
    fetchFirestore() {
      this.$store.dispatch("fetchFirebase");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Great, i have refactored this and your idea on Vuex works, thanks.